# how to change popupmenu Item Color

Tags: android

i want to change the text color of my Dropdown popmenu  from action bar ....
i m using Holo.Light theme
i changed Title Color of actionbar into white
but i m unable to change my pop menu text color u can see on attached image

here is my style theme

```
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/PopupMenuListView</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/PopupMenuTextView</item>
            <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
            <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item>
             <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar</item>
         <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
    </style>
     <style name="myTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>

</style>

    <!-- Change Overflow Menu ListView Divider Property -->
        <style name="PopupMenuListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
            <item name="android:divider">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
            <item name="android:dividerHeight">1sp</item>
            <item name="android:listSelector">#000000</item>
        </style>

        <!-- Change Overflow Menu ListView Text Size and Text Size -->
        <style name="PopupMenuTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
            <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
            <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
            <item name="android:drawablePadding">25dp</item>

        </style>

        <!-- Change Overflow Menu Background -->
        <style name="PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
            <item name="android:popupBackground">#A21E1E</item>
        </style>
```

Comment: use spannable string and change text color dynamically

Comment: can i not change popmenulistview color

Comment: may be i dnt know exactly but spannable string is working pefectly.i tried my self.

Answer (score 0):

after battling so much with various tries from various posts, the following worked for me for my PopupMenu and hope this helps someone.  colorBankground is to change the color of your line divider.

```
    <style name="PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/background_medium_gray</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/BackgroundGray</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>

    Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.PopupMenu);
    final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view);

    final MenuInflater menuInflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
```